# Why exactly is prepend to a Scala List a constant time operation, but append a linear time operation?

Tags: scala

I am in the middle of learning Scala right now from Odersky's 'Programming in Scala' and I just read this

> ...the time it takes to append to a list grows linearly with the size of the
>   list, whereas prepending with :: takes constant time...

Why exactly does it take linear time to append to append to a list but only constant time to prepend to it. My current guess is it's somehow implemented as a linked list internally which would explain the difference between the two operations. In that case, how are ListBuffers implemented which have a constant time append?

Comment: List buffers can append in constant time because they mutate cdr pointers. The public list API doesn't allow this, however.

Comment: To append, the entire list needs to be traversed.

Comment: If my response satisfies your question, can you tick it as completed? otherwise please add a comment explaining what else you need to know :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are both implemented similarly to linked lists. The difference is that the ListBuffer contains also a pointer to the tail of the list. Scala's source code is open, if you are curious about its detail you can explore it on github (for example, here is the [ListBuffer](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/9483542b1304601683fbda0fee1eef1c8c10696a/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#l167)'s append code)

Answer (score 18):

There's two questions here: one is a very basic one about lists, and the other is scala-specific. For the first, I'll draw a picture. The "List" abstract data type is one of the oldest in computer science; it goes right back to 1956 and the first implementation of the LISP language.

The list ADT is indeed implemented using a one-way linked list. Each element is traditionally called a cons cell (Nil indicates end of list):

```
+------+------+      +------+------+    +--------+
|   1  |   * -+----> |  3   +   * -+--->|  NIL   |
+------+------+      +-------------+    +--------+
^
|
val list1
```

This corresponds to the chained "cons" (list construction) call in scala:

```
scala> val list1 = 1 :: 3 :: Nil
list1: List[Int] = List(3, 1)
```

List is an immutable data structure. We cannot destructively update it by rewriting any
existing pointer/reference. So what if we want to prepend to it?

```
scala> val list2 = 0 :: list1
list2: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 3)
```

Creating list2 is very fast and easy, we simply create a new cons cell and prepend it to the existing list:

```
+------+------+      +------+------+      +------+------+    +--------+
|   0  |   *--+----->|   1  |   * -+----> |  3   +   * -+--->|  NIL   |
+------+------+      +------+------+      +-------------+    +--------+
 ^                   ^
 |                   |
 val list2           val list1
```

The beauty of this is that it leaves all existing references unchanged, preserving immutability. However, if we want to /append/ to the list, we would have to overwrite the reference to Nil to a new element, thus mutating list1. Thus, the only way to do it is to duplicate the entire existing list and rewrite it thus:

```
scala> val list3 = list1 ++ (5 :: Nil)
list3: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5)


+------+------+      +------+------+      +------+------+    +--------+
|   0  |   *--+----->|   1  |   * -+----> |  3   +   * -+--->|  NIL   |
+------+------+      +------+------+      +-------------+    +--------+
^                    ^                                           ^
|                    |                                           |
val list2            val list1                                   |
                                                                 |
                                                                 |
(copy)                                                           |
+------+------+      +------+------+    +--------+-------+       |
|   1  |   * -+----> |  3   +   * -+--->|   5    |    *--+-------+
+------+------+      +-------------+    +--------+-------+    
^
|
val list3
```

It's a linear time operation because, to append to a list of length N, we have to make copies of all N cons cells (except for Nil).

As for scala's ListBuffer, its append works by directly mutating the backing list, rewriting the tail reference of the final cons cell, which has the slighly awkward looking type ::[A].

In List.scala:

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
   override def tail : List[B] = tl
   override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

[..]
In ArrayList.scala:

```
/** Appends a single element to this buffer. This operation takes constant time.
*
*  @param x  the element to append.
*  @return   this $coll.
*/
def += (x: A): this.type = {
  if (exported) copy()
  if (isEmpty) {
    last0 = new :: (x, Nil)
    start = last0
  } else {
    val last1 = last0
    last0 = new :: (x, Nil)
    last1.tl = last0
  }
  len += 1
  this
}
```

last1.tl = last0 is permitted because ::.tl has visibility private[scala], permitting unsafe "under the hood" operations for mutating collections such as ListBuffer.

Comment: +1 for the immutability of prepend versus the mutability of append. provides a great lesson on the cost of immutability. also, i am not sure why this answer was not marked correct instead of the previous one. it is obviously more detailed and helpful.